# convert html code to Json array using JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I use this function to convert html element to Json file:

```js
function converter(dom) {
        if (dom.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            return dom.nodeValue;
        }
        if (dom.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
            dom = dom.documentElement;
        }
        const obj = {};
        obj.nodeType = dom.nodeType;
        if (dom.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            obj.tagName = dom.tagName;
            obj.attributes = []; // Array.from(obj.attributes) gives us a lot of things we don't want
            for (let i = 0, len = dom.attributes.length; i < len; ++i) {
                const attr = dom.attributes[i];
                obj.attributes.push({name: attr.name, value: attr.value});
            }
            obj.children = [];
            for (let child = dom.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
                obj.children.push(converter(child));
            }
        } else {
            obj.nodeValue = dom.nodeValue;
        }
        return obj;
    }
    const jsonn = JSON.stringify(converter(document.getElementById("examplee")), null, 4);
    
    var data = JSON.parse(jsonn);
    console.log(data);
```

```html
<div id='examplee'>text</div>
```

Now I want to make it accept HTML code in the conveter intstead of DOM

make it work like this:

```js
function converter(dom) {
        if (dom.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            return dom.nodeValue;
        }
        if (dom.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
            dom = dom.documentElement;
        }
        const obj = {};
        obj.nodeType = dom.nodeType;
        if (dom.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            obj.tagName = dom.tagName;
            obj.attributes = []; // Array.from(obj.attributes) gives us a lot of things we don't want
            for (let i = 0, len = dom.attributes.length; i < len; ++i) {
                const attr = dom.attributes[i];
                obj.attributes.push({name: attr.name, value: attr.value});
            }
            obj.children = [];
            for (let child = dom.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
                obj.children.push(converter(child));
            }
        } else {
            obj.nodeValue = dom.nodeValue;
        }
        return obj;
    }
    const jsonn = JSON.stringify(converter("<div>12345</div>"), null, 4);
    
    var data = JSON.parse(jsonn);
    console.log(data);
```

But it returns empty tags. I want it to return the json when I put in the converter.
The problem is it accepts only the `document.getElementById("examplee")` and not accept the code like the snippet above

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but in the first example you're using an HTML element as an argument, whereas in the second example you're using a string as an argument. For that, I've added the following to the beginning of your function:

```
 if (typeof dom === 'string') {
    let tmp = document.createElement('template');
    tmp.innerHTML = dom;
    dom = tmp.content.childNodes[0]
  }
```

```js
function converter(dom) {
  if (typeof dom === 'string') {
    let tmp = document.createElement('template');
    tmp.innerHTML = dom;
    dom = tmp.content.childNodes[0]
  }
  if (dom.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    return dom.nodeValue;
  }
  if (dom.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
    dom = dom.documentElement;
  }
  const obj = {};
  obj.nodeType = dom.nodeType;
  if (dom.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    obj.tagName = dom.tagName;
    obj.attributes = []; // Array.from(obj.attributes) gives us a lot of things we don't want
    for (let i = 0, len = dom.attributes.length; i < len; ++i) {
      const attr = dom.attributes[i];
      obj.attributes.push({
        name: attr.name,
        value: attr.value
      });
    }
    obj.children = [];
    for (let child = dom.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
      obj.children.push(converter(child));
    }
  } else {
    obj.nodeValue = dom.nodeValue;
  }
  return obj;
}
const jsonn = JSON.stringify(converter("<div>12345</div>"), null, 4);

var data = JSON.parse(jsonn);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: yes but I dont want to create new element and put the code in it innerHTML. I want it to work directly